# Problems running CrossOver on a mac

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, crossover

i just downloaded CrossOver on my iMac running OSX Snow Leopard. however when i open it, it shows me this error message:[image]

whats going on, and how can i fix this?

the console errors look like this (i cant make heads or tail of em though):[image]

Comment: Which errors are displayed on the console?

Comment: sorry, forgot to upload em. here you are

Comment: Which versions of Python, if any, do you have installed on your Mac?

Comment: To check the Python version, in a terminal type "python".  It'll show it in the first line "*Python 2.x.x*"

Comment: i have 2.7.3 installed

Comment: You're good there, requires >=2.4  Hmm...

Comment: For some reason the Python script cannot find a value for the HOME environment variable; this is very odd. From the path(s) in the console log it looks like you built CrossOver from source. Is that correct?  Also, how are you launching CrossOver?